# Switch view in view in AngularJS upon click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view

Hello dear Stackoverflow.

I am currently developing a AnguarJS project, and I have made some headway.

However, now I want to change a viewbox another view, on click, and I have difficulty figuring out how to go about this.

So the controller has a factory which in turn have some data (names and age).
The names get loaded into a select with ng-options, and depending on the name, a viewbox will change to display that name and age.

Now I want make a button, which will call a view, which makes it possible to change selected item (I know I need a backend for these actual changes to stick, but for now, I just want it to change).

How should I go about this. (This code is not refactored, but bear with me :) )

**views/home.html:**

```
<div class="container">
        <div clas="row">
            <div style="width: 200px; margin-top: 100px">
            <select  ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="patients.name for patients in patients" class="pull-left form-control" name="Vælg"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="viewbox pull-right">
                <h3>Patient: {{selectedItem.name}}</h3>
                <p>Age: {{selectedItem.age}} </p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row" class="pull-left">
            <div style="width: 200px; margin-top: 100px">
            <form  role="form" class="form-group" ng-submit="addPost()">
                <input  class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="title" />
                <input  class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="age" />
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </form>
            </form>
        </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('KOL', ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: './views/home.html',
                controller: 'kolCtrl'
            });

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    }])
    .factory('patients', [function(){
        var object = {
        patients: [ 

                    {name: 'Erik', age: 42},
                    {name: 'Lars', age: 24},
                    {name: 'Karl', age: 12},
                    {name: 'John', age: 16}


                    ]
       };
        return object;
    }])
    .controller('kolCtrl', ['$scope', 'patients', 
        function($scope, patients){

              $scope.patients = patients.patients;
              $scope.selectedItem = $scope.patients[0];

              $scope.addPost = function() {
                if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
                if(!$scope.age || $scope.age === '') { return; }
                $scope.patients.push({name: $scope.title, age: $scope.age});
                $scope.title = '';
                $scope.age = '';
              };


}])


;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add set the `selectedItem` to the newly added element just do this in the `addPost` function:

```
var newPatient = {name: $scope.title, age: $scope.age}; 
$scope.patients.push(newPatient);
$scope.selectedItem = newPatient;
```

Then the new element will be displayed inside the `viewbox` element.

**Update:**

The original problem was, that `ng-options` needed to be adapted to be able to work with the index of the `patients` array.
The easiest solution was to do the `ng-select` differently:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="patients.indexOf(patient) as patient.name for patient in patients"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But my problem is not so much how to add a new patient. 

Say you select a patient from my select box, and it shows in my viewbox. (Which works). What I am trying to achieve, if possible, is when selected patient is in the viewbox, there is going to be a button.

When you click on this button (in the view), the view changes to another, in which you can edit said patient. 

Hope it makes it more clear :)

Comment: Of course there is. The easiest way to do that is to make an action for the button which fills the ng-model (age, title) from the input with the data from the selected patient. The only thing you need to take care of is, that you distinguish between an edit and an add submission. On edit you just update the patient in the array. I hope that makes it clear. If not I can elaborate an example.

Comment: If you have the time to make an example, I'd much appreciate it! :)

Comment: You propably need this because you want to replace the updated patient in the array right? If yes, I can give you an example how to do it without needing the $index.

Comment: Well, to be honest, it is not updating or creating new patients.
It's to show the view, with the details of the patient I select in the list. Does that make sense or should I make it more clear? :)

Comment: I'd appreciate it. I thought you wanted to fill the input with the data you have selected so that you can update a patient...

Comment: Okay! so I have this array of objects (with patient data) in my app.js.
In my view, I've made a select list with options. When I select one of the patients, the viewbox (which is on the same page) gets updated with details of the patient I selected. 

Now, my next step, is to make a button within this viewbox with the patient details, which will link to a page or partial with the complete info of this patient. (In this, I will make the data editable, but is not the focus right now). Sorry to have been unclear, hope this helps! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96490/discussion-between-jacob-and-floriantopf).